# Store very big numbers in an integer in C

Tags: c, numbers, integer

I need to store a very large number as an integer in a C program, `unsigned long int` is still too small, I need a very large data type that will still work with the modulo operator (%).

Comment: How about unsigned long long? That's often 64 bits.

Comment: Use an arbitrary precision integer library ([some links here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries))

Comment: Sometimes the modulo operation itself can be avoided. If you can do all of your arithmetic using modulo arithmetic, and you only would take the modulo of the final result, then the modulo operation can be dropped.

Comment: Write your own "double precision long" support.  It's not that hard.

Comment: "I need a very large data type" is an unbounded goal.  Provide more details.

Answer (score 5):

There are several libraries that can do this

- [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)
- [OpenSSL's BN](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html)

If you need it for cryptographic purposes (e.g. RSA as hinted by your need of modulo arithmetic), OpenSSL BN is ideally suited

Comment: It is a challenge problem, not for cryptography, and big number arithmetic or cryptographic routines are the wrong way to go. (I suspected from the question text, but the OP’s history shows a prior question about Project Euler.) I expect the problem is designed to be within range of normal integers provided the modulo properties are used intelligently.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to find how many factors there are of a number with 12 digits

Comment: @DylanCleaver: Include `<stdint.h>` and use `uint64_t` if your C implementation supports it. You may also need `<inttypes.h>` and the format specifiers it provides if you need to read large numbers from input.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to throw in another library to solve this problem, which I just finished:

- [kmbint](https://github.com/mexok/kmbint)

It is more lightweight than the previous mentioned libraries. Please be sure that it still solves your needs, as there are some limitations.

As an example you might do modulo operations like this:

```
char i[20] = "5005";
kmbint_mod(i, "10");
// i is now "5"
```